# Does there exists an automorphism of $\Bbb{C}$ that's also an exponential hom?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers, field-theory

Is there an automorphism of the field $\Bbb{C}$ of complex numbers, $\phi$, such that for all $z, w \in \Bbb{C}$ we have in addition to being a ring hom, $\phi(z^w) = \phi(z)^{\phi(w)}$?

Comment: $z^w$ is not well-defined, unless you pick an essentially arbitrary branch of $\log z$.

Comment: What is $z^w$ ?

Comment: The most obvious one is complex conjugation. Since it's a continuous automorphism, and $\log \overline z=\overline{\log z}$ for the "standard" branch cut for $\log$,  you get the exponential hom. Or if you treat $z^w$ as a multi-valued function, you get a hom, too. Are you looking for another one?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Well, that one is not the most obvious ;)